# 1230C | Codeforces | Find count of numbers that divide all numbers in an array

Tags: algorithms

Here is the question: [Link](https://codeforces.com/contest/1203/problem/C). In a gist, we need to count the total count of numbers that would divide every number in an array.

The approach that I took was that any number that has to divide all the numbers must be less than or equal to the smallest number in the array. For e.g., if the array is `[6 90 12 18 30 18]` - any divisor cannot be greater than 6, because that would not divide 6.

Based on above logic, here's the code that I wrote:

```
#include <bits/stdc++.h>

using namespace std;

//output
#define output(x) cout << x << endl
#define ll long long

int main(int argc, char const *argv[])
{ 
    int n;
    cin >> n;

    vector<ll> v(n);

    ll smallest = LONG_MAX;
    for (auto &it: v) {
        cin >> it;

        if (it < smallest) {
            smallest = it;
        }
    }

    set<ll> divisors;

    for (ll i = 1; i*i <= smallest; i++) {
        if (smallest%i == 0) {
            ll q = smallest/i;
            divisors.insert(i);
            divisors.insert(q);
        }
    }


    for (auto &it: v) {
        vector<ll> removeEl;

        for (auto &div: divisors) {
            if (it%div != 0) {
                removeEl.push_back(div);
            }
        }

        for (auto &rem: removeEl) {
            divisors.erase(rem);
        }
    }

    output(divisors.size());


    return 0;
}
```

This fails [wrong answer] on some test case - is there something incorrect in my implementation or my approach to the question?

Comment: is it a set, so it cannot.

Comment: What is the test case it failed (like input, output and expected output)?

Comment: Not entirely coming on codeforces, it is too big.

Comment: Basically, the minimum that I have taken is LONG_MAX - while, in the question, the data in the array can go upto 10^12, hence, in the case where it failed, LONG_MAX was the minimum and hence the algorithm was incorrectly working. Nothing else is wrong here.a

Comment: Confirmed, `smallest` should be initialized to LONG_LONG_MAX since, on current Codeforces.com,  LONG_MAX=2147483647 while LONG_LONG_MAX=9223372036854775807. ```#include<iostream>
#include<climits>
int main() { std::cout << LONG_MAX << std::endl << LONG_LONG_MAX << std::endl; }``` at https://codeforces.com/problemset/customtest .

Comment: Coding questions and checking your code is off-topic here.  Not everyone here reads C++.  If you want to know about the algorithm, we ask you to write concise pseudocode.  If you want to know about your code, I'm afraid that isn't suitable here for this site.

Comment: Please make the problem statement self-contained, so we can understand what task you are solving without having to click on an external link.  (In fact, when I click on that link, I get an error page.)